# How to get current object/instance in save_form (intermediate save page)

Tags: django

I have the following code where I'd like to modify the confirmation page by making it show some in the admin backend the elements which will be modified/affected after confirming it.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the current instance. Could you please help me? (I think it's through the request variable).

If you know another way of doing so instead of by modifying the save_form I'd appreciate it to know.

Thank you.

```
Class MyClass(modelAdmin):

 def save_form(self, request, form, change):
  instance = ?????
  query = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
  if 'apply' in request.POST:
   for object in query:
    somefunction(object)
  return render(request, 'path/template.html', context='affected_elements', query)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django [(at least in 2.2)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin.save_model), the signature of [`ModelAdmin.save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) is:

> save_model(self, request, **obj**, form, change):

To access the instance, you can use `obj`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but I don't understand how I can add/change the intermediate page of the Save action with the save_model